# Collate column to SQL default collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I'm trying to collate a column to the SQL default collation, but can't make it work.

All answers I see are related to database default and not the SQL default

I tried this `Alter table x alter column name nvarchar(max) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT` but it will give me the database default which is different from the SQL default. (Hebrew vs SQL_LATIN)

I'm also trying to do it with select, but it seems impossible.

This is what I have tried :
`Alter table x alter column name nvarchar(max) COLLATE (Select SERVERPROPERTY('collation'))`

Comment: Please show your full query and what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: When you say "SQL default" do you mean the server default?

Comment: ["collation_name can be only a specified Windows_collation_name or a SQL_collation_name and the parameter must contain a literal value. collation_name cannot be represented by a variable or expression."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15) You need a dynamic sql for that.

Comment: @Serg or `DATABASE_DEFAULT`

Comment: @DaleK I need to Collate the column to this "Select SERVERPROPERTY('collation')"

Comment: @Yalin then that is called the Server Collation **not** the SQL Default Collation.

Comment: And why not just hardcode it? How many servers are you planning on running this on?

Comment: @DaleK we have different customers across the world, so it needs to be dynamic

Comment: @Serg from your comment I didn't understand if we can do it or not?

Comment: Serg said you can do it, using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Please update your question from "SQL default" to "Server default"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Serg said you can use dynamic sql. Try the following code:

```
SELECT  [name], [collation_name] 
FROM    sys.columns 
WHERE   [object_id] = OBJECT_ID( N'x.dbo.x', N'U') /*table name*/
    AND [name] = 'name'                            /*column name*/

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
,       @ServerCollation nvarchar(100)

SELECT @ServerCollation = CAST( SERVERPROPERTY( N'Collation') AS nvarchar(max))
SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.x ALTER COLUMN [name] nvarchar(max) COLLATE ' + @ServerCollation
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

SELECT  [name], [collation_name] 
FROM    sys.columns 
WHERE   [object_id] = OBJECT_ID( N'x.dbo.x', N'U') 
    AND [name] = 'name'
```

Answer (score -1):

To check server level collation, use:

```
 SELECT CONVERT (varchar(256), SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));
```

To alter column lever collations, use:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN mycol NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE Greek_CS_AI;  //Replace Greek_CS_AI with the actual value.
```

Comment: I think its clear from the question that OP is trying to avoid hardcoding it.

Comment: @DaleK you are right, thanks.